# rand not determined on nginx/php-fpm

Tags: php, random

In my script I use `srand(date("Ymd"))` for generating determined random numbers in the same sequence all the day. This runs well on my local and apache environment.

On nginx/php-fpm as I have it on the live environment, the `rand()` is generating another sequence of numbers even though srand was initialized with the same number.

Is there another, more reliable seed function or do i need to write an own generator?

Comment: Why is it important to have the same numbers generated in both environments?

Comment: no, target is to generate the same sequence when running the script at 00:00:01 and also the same at 23:59:59 on the same host.

Comment: So you're saying that under php-fpm, even though you use `srand()`, the first value of `rand()` is different each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `mt_srand()` and `mt_rand()` instead.

The `rand()` and `srand()` functions that you're using now make use of the random functions built into the host operating system. This means that when you move from one platform to another, you're potentially using an entirely different number generator.

By contrast, the `mt_rand()` function uses a Mersenne Twister algorithm built into PHP itself to generate its random numbers.

In theory this means that the sequence should be more predictable going from one platform to another.

You may still find that the sequence changes if you move from a 32-bit to a 64-bit PHP build, but other than that I'd expect it to give the same sequence in all cases, given the same seed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Within each fork, this is right. However, for overall determined random, I had to write a custom pseudo-random method temporarily. After upgrade to latest PHP, this is fixed.